# Showing $ \displaystyle\int_{t-1}^t \log{x}\mathrm dx < \log{t} $

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals, logarithms, monotone-functions

How can I show that

$$
\int_{t-1}^t \log{x}dx < \log{t}
$$

I can calculate the integral of $\log{x}$ as, $x\log{x}-x$.   But after calculating, definite integral and re-aranging, I am not able to get the desired result.  Is it true that the above inequality holds true for any monotonic function ?

Comment: So you don't need to integrate $\log(x)$ to prove this, you can use the general comparison property for integrals instead. But if you want to do the integral explicitly, you should get $x \log(x) - x$ as the antiderivative. But then you have a bit of complication in doing estimates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $x\in[t-1,t)$ , $\log(x)<\log(t)$ and $\log$ is a continuous function. Therefore\begin{align}\int_{t-1}^t\log(x)\,\mathrm dx&<\int_{t-1}^t\log(t)\,\mathrm dx\\&=\bigl(t-(t-1)\bigr)\log(t)\\&=\log(t).\end{align}